# LinearGradientBrush does not render correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, gdi

Consider the following code from a standard `System.Windows.Forms.Form`

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    Rectangle test = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);
    using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(test, Color.Red, Color.Blue, 0f))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(brush, 8), test);
    }
}
```

It produces this result:

[image]

Why are the red and blue lines showing up in the incorrect order, and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rendering origin is the problem.  You are asking for a `Pen` that is 8px wide, and that 8px is defined as outward 4px in both directions from the line defined by your rectangle.  That is due to the default value of `Alignment=Center`.  If you set the `Pen` to use `Alignment=Inset`, you will have better results.

You can see this line by simply adding this to your original code:

```
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, test);
```

Change your method to be this, and it will work:

```
Rectangle test = new Rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100);
using (LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(test, Color.Red, Color.Blue, 0f))
{
    using (var pen = new Pen(brush, 8f))
    {
        pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, test);
    }
}
```