# Graphics.DrawPath and LinearGradientBrush issue

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, gdi, lineargradientbrush

In relation to this question that I asked a few weeks ago now

[LinearGradientBrush does not render correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901068/lineargradientbrush-does-not-render-correctly)

Consider the following code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 100);
    using(LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.Red, Color.Blue, 90))
    {
        using(Pen pen = new Pen(brush, 1))
        {
            pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }            
}
```

Produces this result...

[image: Brush]

Why is there a red line where there should be a blue line, and how do I fix this?

Pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset didn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pens (or the Graphics DrawMethods) have a tendency to draw outside their boundaries.  I think Microsoft considered that a feature, but I never understood it.

Try using a smaller rectangle for the pen:

```
using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.Red, Color.Blue, 90)) {
  using (Pen pen = new Pen(brush, 1)) {
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y,
                                                rect.Width - 1, rect.Height - 1));
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it helps. And I suspect the DrawRectangle method as opposed to the FillRectangle..

Comment: @TaW Either-Or I guess.  DrawMethods take Pens, FillMethods take brushes.  Annoyingly, they never draw in the same exact rectangle.

Comment: Ah I see...when I drew a 32x32 rect and inspected it with Paint, it was actually 33x33. Thanks, this has helped a lot! :-)

Comment: This solves half the issue...try this principle with new Rectangle(10, 10, 40, 23)...I get a rectangle with the correct size but blue top and bottom rather than red top and bottom...any ideas?

Comment: Actually it's blue top and bottom when the angle is 270. It's still red top and bottom if the angle is 90. Even with a slightly smaller rectangle, it's still an issue in some respects

Comment: @series0ne I suspect it's your odd numbered height.  Setting the PixelOffsetMode to Half doesn't solve it either.  Not sure about the work-around for that, other than make it even.

Answer (score 1):

OK, to sum it up: `DrawRectangle` always **overdraws** by 1 pixel (*) and the `LinearGradientBrush` therefore restarts with the 1st color.

Yes, Lars got one solution, but here is an interesting alternative:

```
  brush.WrapMode = WrapMode.TileFlipXY;
```

This makes sure that the gradient doesn't start at the beginning when it has to overdraw but reverses in both directions, so the extra pixel is drawn in the right Color and you don't need to manipulate one of the two the `Rectangle` Sizes..

Well ok, if you need total precision it is probably second best, as the last row and column will have the same color as their neighbours..but not having to deal with two sizes may be worth it..

(*) Which is why you **can't** use it to draw a `1x1` square/pixel. Instead you need to use `FillRectangle`..

Comment: Interesting solution, +1 for knowledge. Actually, I think manipulating the rectangle size is the correct solution, for example if I define a 32x32 rectangle, DrawRectangle will overdraw and create a rectangle that is 33x33 (providing the pen is 1px wide). That being said, I'm not discounting this code gem...I think this could come in handy (although I'm guessing the move to WPF is killing off all System.Drawing, GDI and Windows Forms stuff! :-(

Comment: Well, that move is sill wainting to happen; less than 20% of all new project are WPF.. Agreed on your solution being correct, though ;-)

Comment: I think the only problem with WPF is the learning curve. I've started using it a little but I've basically had to throw away everything I know about WinForms. That being said; I don't think WPF will feature in the cross platform .NET Core/vNext libraries, so I guess Winforms is still the way to go for Developing cross platform desktop applications

Comment: Thanks, this works great when using points to draw a single line with a LinearGradientBrush. eg new LinearGradientBrush(New Point(StartX, StartY),                                                        New Point(EndX, EndY), Color.Green, Color.Yellow)